# In a chain, if a card will be banished : can I still activate its effects?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So here's the situation: my opponent has a Vendread Chimera with the following effect (thanks to houndhorde): *"Once per turn (Quick Effect): You can target 1 Spell/Trap your opponent controls; banish it"*.

2 cases :

1. I activate Switcheroroo (trap card), and as a quick effect, he banishes it with Chimera. Does the switcheroroo effect still happens?
2. He banishes my switcheroroo (face down) as a quick effect. Can I activate it as a response?

He says the effect of a card doesn't resolve if it is banished in a chain, and he also says I can't activate cards that are going to be banished.
I think exactly the opposite for both cases since it doesn't negate.

Answer (score 2):

1. The effects of Switcheroroo still happen. There is no negation on Houndhorde. It's like chaining Twister to a trap for example. Trap still goes off.
2. You can chain your trap to that. He declares he's going to banish > You chain Switcheroroo > Card gets banished > Switcheroroo effect goes off in the chain. The only time this is different is when the card specifically states the card it's targeting (or any card) can't be chained. I can't find an example but I know some cards do state this.

For that last statement, you're absolutely correct. Banishing is just banishing. If it doesn't say it negates, it's not going to be negated.

Comment: An example for point 2 can be [night beam](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Night_Beam), do note that you can chain a different card and then you can chain the targeted card